# Why is this javascript value null at the scope it is declared but not within a narrower scope

Tags: javascript, scope

Let's say I have the following code that resizes an image using a `canvasResize` plugin and then returns the processed Blob data.

If I put the `alert` of the `f` variable where it is now, `f` will not be null. However if I try to inspect the `f` variable immediately before it is returned at the end of the function, then it will be null.

```
function resizeFile(file){
    var f=null;
    $.canvasResize(file,
        {
            width: 400,
            height: 0,
            crop: false,
            quality: 100,
            callback: function (data)
                {
                    // Add file data
                    f = $.canvasResize('dataURLtoBlob', data)
                    if(f!=null){
                                alert(f)
                            }
                            else{
                                alert("file blob is null")
                            }
                    $('body').css("background", "url("+data+")")
                }
        });


        return f;
    }
```

Comment: Seems like the previous commenter removed his/her comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the `f` variable is initialized in the `callback` function which is executed after the resize is done.

So, `return f` is called first and then the `callback` function so it will be `null`.

Comment: Thanks that's right, a previous commenter mentioned that it is because of the async nature of the callback, which for some reason didn't click at first.